# Why do we need JAXB bean when configuring JSON for RESTful web services?

Tags: jaxb, jax-rs

I'm reading the tutorial about configuring JSON for RESTful web services:
https://blogs.oracle.com/enterprisetechtips/entry/configuring_json_for_restful_web

JAXB defines how Java objects are converted from and to XML.

However I don't understand why we have to JAXB bean model when creating RESTful web services that return JSON response? After all it is JSON not XML, right?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> However I don't understand why we have to JAXB bean model when
>   creating RESTful web services that return JSON response?

**Short Answer**

You don't have to use JAXB to create a RESTful service using a JAX-RS framework.  JAX-RS provides the `MessageBodyReader`/`MessageBodyWriter` mechanism to plug-in whatever binding you want.  JSON binding providers often include an implementation of these classes that you can use directly.  Below is an example of how to do this with [**EclipseLink MOXy**](http://www.eclipse.org/eclipselink/moxy.php) (I'm the tech lead):

- http://blog.bdoughan.com/2012/05/moxy-as-your-jax-rs-json-provider.html

**Advantage of Using JAXB**

Applying a JAXB mapping provides an easy mechanism to provide one set of mappings to get both an XML and JSON representation of your data.